# Can a one-sided p-value ever be larger than a two-sided p-value?

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, p-value

Intuition tells me no because when you find a two-sided p-value, you're finding the p-value of one tail and then multiplying by 2. But are there certain situations where it can be larger than a one-sided p-value?

Comment: Test it in the less favorable direction. By definition, the two-sided $p$-value comes from the test in the more favorable direction times two.

Answer (score 3):

Yes because in the simplest example you have two possible definitions for your one sided tests. Let's go with the following setup:

> Two-sided test: $H \ne 0$

And

> One-sided test: $H < 0$

Let's say we get significant results after running our experiment with p-values of 0.0002 and 0.0001 respectively. In this case your statement is correct.

However what if we had defined the following hypotheses:

> Two-sided test: $H \ne 0$

And

> One-sided test: $H > 0$

Then with the same data as before we would get p-values of 0.0002 and 0.9999, respectively. So here the one-sided test gave us a p-value that was significantly higher because our hypothesis had the effect going the wrong way.

So in general yes it is possible to have one-sided p-values that are larger than the two-sided p-value.

Reference: https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faq-what-are-the-differences-between-one-tailed-and-two-tailed-tests/